# font-face not working in IE & chrome

Tags: asp.net, css, font-face

I'm using following code to display a custom font in my ASP.NET web site:

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: 'B Mitra';
    src: url('BMitra.ttf') format('truetype'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('BMitra.ttf?#iefix') format('truetype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('BMitra.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('BMitra.ttf')  format('truetype'); /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    }
    </style>
</head>


<body style="font-family:B Mitra;" onload="pageLoad()">
```

it works fine in FireFox, but IE and chrome don't display my custom font (this custom font is located in my server, in the folder which contains my ASPX file, font is downloaded on systems that don't have it in firefox, but I think IE and chrome cannot download it and another existing font is used). what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.adtrak.co.uk/blog/font-face-chrome-rendering/

Why are you just calling the same format('truetype') over and over again? Having the comments next to it won't fix it for modern browsers. I think you need to have the other file formats too? that is, typically:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'chunk-webfont';
src: url('../../includes/fonts/chunk-webfont.eot');
src: url('../../includes/fonts/chunk-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
url('../../includes/fonts/chunk-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
url('../../includes/fonts/chunk-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('../../includes/fonts/chunk-webfont.svg') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
@font-face {
font-family: 'chunk-webfont';
src: url('../../includes/fonts/chunk-webfont.svg') format('svg');

}
}
```

Comment: thanks but I only have a ttf file, how can I find other format of my font? should I convert them? you mean I should use other formats for IE or chrome? everything works fine in FireFox

Comment: Converting would be the simplest and it's what I would do. There are a couple of places to do that, like here

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: if you're not converting, this person has the font you need in the formats you need

https://github.com/sobhe/jahadi/tree/master/static/fonts